# Why can't I see any text in Flask from my html document?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a webpage using flask and html with

`render_template()`

but I cant see any text from my html document. I see the `<title>` appear, but nothing from the paragraphs is showing up.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('', template_folder='/home/runner/Alix')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return render_template('home.html')

def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    server = Thread(target=run)
    server.start()
```

I am using the keep_alive() function in a separate file, with a discord bot.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>[ALIX FLASK SERVER]<title>

        <style>
          body{
            background_color: black;
          }

        </style>


    <head>

    <body>
      <p>
        This text wont show
      </p>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: the background color is still white too

Comment: the closing ```<title>``` tag is missing a forward slash ```/```, as in ```</title>```

Comment: Your head tag and title tag is not closed. See line 3 and 13. 

Should be <title>[ALIX FLASK SERVER]</title> and </body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed the head tag, the second one should be `</head>`

Comment: Also the title tag, I just noticed it and I am beyond mortified.